# How to fix no usable data when trying to run coverage report in GitHub Actions CI Workflow?

Tags: github-actions

I have tried multiple ways to debug this, but to no avail.

I have a situation where my coverage job in the Github Actions CI workflow for an open source I forked is unable to do so.

The original package was called `django_ltree`. I wanted to keep the app with the same name but the package named differently as the repo seems to be unmaintained and I wanted to separate from the original source.

For some reason, the github ci keep failing at the combining coverage part.

So i have tried everything including renaming it to the new name `greendeploy_django_ltree`

The GitHub ci still fails at the same spot.

[image]

This is the url for the above screenshot.

https://github.com/GreenDeploy-io/greendeploy-django-ltree/actions/runs/6131727755/job/16641968397

This is my workflow file: https://github.com/GreenDeploy-io/greendeploy-django-ltree/actions/runs/6131727755/workflow

As you can see at

```
- name: Debug coverage data before combining
        run: python -m coverage debug data

      - name: Debug - Check if .coverage exists
        run: test -f .coverage && echo ".coverage exists" || echo ".coverage does NOT exist"

      # previously: python -m coverage combine ./.coverage  # specify the file
      - name: Combine coverage data
        run: |
          python -m coverage combine
```

I tried to debug and the .coverage file did exists. And when I debug, you can clearly see that coverage data states which lines are covered.

But for some reason, when it comes to combine, it goes haywired.

I have commented out the various matrix so that it runs faster. but I envisioned putting it back on.

I honestly don't know what's wrong

my pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
addopts = --strict-markers --cov=greendeploy_django_ltree --cov-report=term-missing --cov-config=.coveragerc --cov-report=term
python_files = test_*.py
```

my .coveragerc

```
[run]
omit =
    **/migrations/*
```

All my tests are running successfully except for this issue with the combining coverage.